# How can I list only sites that use a particular theme or plugin?

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes, mysql, wp-cli

I need to search through dozens of WordPress multisite (network enabled) installs for sites that use a particular plugin.

How can I list only sites that use a particular theme or plugin, preferably with either WP CLI or a database query?

Answer (score 0):

WP CLI is the easiest option here.

First, we want an array/list we can store the desired sites in:

```bash
results=()
```

Then, we get a list of all sites as a variable, and loop over them:

```bash
blogs=$(wp site list --fields="blog_id" --format="csv")
for entry in $blogs
do
    if [ "${entry}" == "blog_id" ]; then
        continue # skip the CSV header
    fi
```

Next, grab the sites active theme:

```bash
    theme=$(wp theme list --status=active --format=csv --fields="name" --url="${entry}" | sed -n 2p)
```

Here I'm using `| sed -n 2p` to get the second line of output in order to skip the CSV header.

Then, if the sites theme matches what we're looking for, add it to a list:

```bash
    if $theme == 'mytheme';
    if [ "${theme}" == "mytheme" ]; then
        results+=($entry)
    fi
```

Then we close our loop

```bash
done
```

Turn our list into a comma separated string, and pass it to `wp site list` via `--sites__in`:

```bash
wp site list --site__in="${results[*]}"
```

We could also swap the retrieval of the theme and the check for a `wp plugin is-active` call if we wanted to filter by active plugin, e.g. `wp plugin is-active hello`

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/is-active/